# magento 2 configurable product out of stock

Tags: magento2

i have on line store built on Magento 2.2.2 version. we sell uniform and safety wear. when creating a configurable product with child products that has sizes, and if make the inventory of one size zero then all sizes show on the front end except the out of stock size. is this Magento default ?? as i like for the out of stock size to still show but customer cannot choose it.

Answer (score 1):

**To be able to activate this configuration:**

go to **Products -> Catalog**, there we choose any product and we go to the option of Quantity. Under it, there is the option "**advanced inventory**", click on it and select the first box that says Use configuration options found under Manage stock.

**This configuration will show all the Sizes**

Comment: it is Yes now, still the out of stock product not being shown

Comment: @jafarpinjar Did you find any solution?